# Tradeoff of CSS segments and JS functions placement order in source code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is not a technical but long lasting problem for me. For CSS codes, I used to put styles for DOM elements (class and id) in the order which is corresponding to their appearance sequence in the HTML codes.

The problem is that when the codes are getting longer and longer, it wastes (non-trivial) time for me to locate correct position to insert or modify a style.

The similar case happens to the JS codes also, in which I place functions in calling sequence.

The result is that I sometimes want to quickly write my thoughts down, and just append a style/function in the end of the css/js codes, and the sequence/ordering is interrupted which further increase the time that I search for code snippet.

I use Sublime Text mostly. And search function only helps if I know the keywords in css class or function name.

Is there any design or habit or tool to increase the efficiency for locating code segment in long source file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post originally targeted CSS Hacks, but I suppose it applies in your situation as well. Harry Roberts advocates putting CSS hacks in a separate file, so that you can, for example, better remember what hacky stuff you should fix later. Or find out who screwed up the css or how it got that way.

You could use a shame.css file to put quick changes into (I do this) and once you're satisfied with the changes, you put it back into your organized structure.

[Link to blog post](http://csswizardry.com/2013/04/shame-css/)

Also, there are some CSS Organizers available such as [Styleneat](http://www.styleneat.com/). This way you can write css all over the place, and run it through the organizer later (once you are satisfied) to have neat code.

For javascript, you can use a similar shame.css tactic, or organize your javascript using an AMD (Asynchronous Module Definition) tool such as [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

Comment: I like the shame.css approach - easy to understand and manage. Also thanks for the other resources.